# Can RStudio show number of changes done to an object after a line is run (as in Stata)?

Tags: r

In Stata, when changing values to variables (or other related operations), the output includes a comment regarding the number of changes. E.g:

[image]

Is there a way to obtain similar commentary in RStudio?

For instance, sometimes I want to check how many changes a command made (partly to see if command worked, or to count the extent of a potential problem in the data). Currently, I have to inspect the data manually or do a pretty uninformative comparison using `all()`, for instance.

Comment: Base R tools do not tend to report change-counts like this, and I'm not familiar with packages/functions that report it in this manner.

Comment: If you are using the `dplyr` function R, the [tidylog](https://github.com/elbersb/tidylog) package would be helpful for some of these tasks.

Answer (score 1):

Base R doesn't do this, but you could write a function to do it, and then instead of saying

```
x <- y
```

you'd say

```
x <- showChanges(x, y)
```

For example,

```r
library(waldo)

showChanges <- function(oldval, newval) {
  print(compare(oldval, newval))
  newval
}

set.seed(123)

x <- 1:100
x <- showChanges(x, x + rbinom(100, size = 1, prob = 0.01))
#> `old[21:27]`: 21 22 23 24 25 26 27
#> `new[21:27]`: 21 22 23 25 25 26 27
x
#>   [1]   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18
#>  [19]  19  20  21  22  23  25  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32  33  34  35  36
#>  [37]  37  38  39  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49  50  51  52  53  54
#>  [55]  55  56  57  58  59  60  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69  70  71  72
#>  [73]  73  74  75  76  77  78  79  80  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89  90
#>  [91]  91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99 100
```

<sup>Created on 2021-10-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>